# Weird results when implementing Sobel Filter

Tags: c, image-processing

I have been learning about computer vision and wanted to implement some simple techniques in C. For the first technique, I am doing the Sobel edge detection filter. I understand how it works and so I thought it should be fairly easy to code, but I am getting very weird results.

I am using the following image:

[image: Box]

and getting this as a result

[image: Filtered box]

New Results!:

[image: Filtered box...a little more correct]

It should be noted that I am using the .ppm image format (the links are to jpgs since I could not find an image host that supports .ppm)

Anyways, here is the section of my code that implements Sobel:

```
/**********************************************************
This program takes in an image file and applies the Sobel
Filter edge detection technique to it.
**********************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ppmReader.h"

void sobelFilter(){


    //Sobel kernels dx (horizontal) and dy (vertical)
    int horizFilter[3][3] = {{ 1,   0,  -1},
                             { 2,   0,  -2},
                             { 1,   0,  -1}};
    int vertFilter[3][3]  = {{ 1,   2,   1},
                             { 0,   0,   0},
                             {-1,  -2,  -1}};
    int pixVal = 0; 
    int horizPixVal = 0;
    int vertPixVal = 0;
    int x, y, i, j;

    //Quick check to make sure dimensions are correct
    printf("Using a Width of: %d\n", width);
    printf("Using a Height of: %d\n\n", height);

    //Start filtering process here
    for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
            pixVal = 0;
            horizPixVal = 0;
            vertPixVal = 0;
            if(!((x == 0) || (x == width-1) || (y == 0) || (y == height-1))){           //If the current pixel is along the border, ignore it and set to zero
                for(i = -1; i <= 1; i++){                                               //because the kernel does not align to it
                    for(j = -1; j <= 1; j++){
                        horizPixVal += (int)(image[y + j][x + i][0]) * horizFilter[i + 1][j + 1];       //Only need to focus on one of the RGB values since the output is
                        vertPixVal  += (int)(image[y + j][x + i][0]) * vertFilter[i + 1][j + 1];        //greyscale and all three values are the same
                    }
                }
            }
            pixVal = sqrt((horizPixVal * horizPixVal) + (vertPixVal * vertPixVal));     //Calculate magnitude
            pixVal = sqrt(horizPixVal * horizPixVal);
            if(pixVal > 255) pixVal = 255;                                              //Clamp value within 8-bit range
            filteredImage[y][x][0] = (unsigned char)pixVal;                             
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that reads the .ppm file:

```
unsigned char image[MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT][MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH][3];
unsigned char filteredImage[MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT][MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH][3];

void readPPMImageData(){
    char fileName[MAX_NAME];
    char imageBuff[MAX_BUFF];
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    maxColor = 0;
    int x;
    int y;

    FILE* file;

    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Now attempting to read in the .ppm image file data...\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("What is the image file name (*.ppm)?  : ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    file = fopen(fileName, "rb");               //open the file specified by the user in binary read mode
    if(file == NULL){                           //but if the file was not found, terminate program
        printf("\nThe file %s could not be found! Terminating program...\n", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    //The first step is to read in the file type and check it agains P6 (file type of .ppm images)
    fgets(imageBuff, MAX_BUFF, file);
    if(imageBuff[0] != 'P' || imageBuff[1] != '6'){
        printf("\nInvalid image type! Acceptable type is: %s --- Received type is: %c%c\n\n", "P6", imageBuff[0], imageBuff[1]);
    }
    printf("Magic Number is: %c%c\n", imageBuff[0], imageBuff[1]);

    while(width == 0 || height == 0){
        fgets(imageBuff, MAX_BUFF, file);
        if(imageBuff[0] != '#') {
            sscanf(imageBuff, "%d %d", &width, &height);
        }
    }
    printf("Width is: %d\n", width);
    printf("Height is: %d\n", height);
    //if(feof(file)){
    //
    //}

    while(maxColor == 0){
        fgets(imageBuff, MAX_BUFF, file);
        if(imageBuff[0] != '#') {
            sscanf(imageBuff, "%d", &maxColor);
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum color value is: %d\n", maxColor);

    for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
            image[y][x][0] = (unsigned char)fgetc(file); //Get Red value
            image[y][x][1] = (unsigned char)fgetc(file); //Get Green value
            image[y][x][2] = (unsigned char)fgetc(file); //Get Blue value
        }
    }
    printf("Finished reading image data!\n\n");

    fclose(file);
}
```

And here is the code that creates the new .ppm file after filtering:

```
void createPPMImage(){
    char fileName[MAX_NAME]; 
    FILE* file;
    int x;
    int y;

    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Now attempting to create new .ppm image file...\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("What is the name of the output image file (*.ppm)?  : ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    printf("Width is: %d\n", width);
    printf("Height is: %d\n", height);
    printf("Maximum color value is: %d\n", maxColor);

    file = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    fputs("P6\n", file);
    fprintf(file, "%d %d\n", width, height);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", maxColor);

    for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
            fputc(filteredImage[y][x][0], file); //Write Red value
            fputc(filteredImage[y][x][0], file); //Write Green value
            fputc(filteredImage[y][x][0], file); //Write Blue value
        }
    }
    printf("Finished creating new filtered image!\n\n");

    fclose(file);
}
```

I'm 100% sure the issue isn't with the reading or writing of the image as I tested those functions without the filter applied and only get issues once I use the above function.

Any help is appreciated because as far as I can see, the indexing/formula seems to be correctly implemented but that is obviously not true.

**EDIT**: As Dave and others have pointed out, I am no longer 100% sure that the error is within the Sobel function and it appears this is just some indexing mistake I have made when using the .ppm format. I went ahead and posted the code for my .ppm reader/writer functions and the new results I am getting after applying the [y][x][color] scheme propsed by anatolyg below. I am sorry if my post is way too long and if it is please let me know as this is my first post and I am not entirely sure what is proper yet.

Comment: You should debug this with some much smaller, simpler test images (e.g. all '1's, or a solitary '1').

Comment: I can't see any obvious issue in that code (certainly not one which would give the output you're seeing), although there are a few smaller issues (e.g. you shouldn't use an array of pointers for an image; use a single 1D array instead for speed). Your issue is almost certainly with code before or after that, despite your belief.

Comment: @Dave - I agree about the 1D array and was planning on doing that after I fixed the issue to make the code a little cleaner. I had started with the 3d array going off of someone else's example but got caught up in this issue and decided that the sloppy array could take a backseat. Glad you could confirm my thoughts that there's no obvious issues, the calculations seem to be correct.

Comment: @Oli - I will try smaller images in order to get raw data points for debugging, thanks

Comment: How did you set up / allocate memory for `image` and `filteredImage`? Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: @ stakx - I have posted the allocations above in the code block for my .ppm reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are usually indexed with `y` coordinate first and `x` second, like this:

```
... image[y + j][x + i] ...
```

This is a convention that keeps people from getting confused when dealing with images in C. Unfortunately, it kinda contradicts the one that Matlab uses, so I just hope you are doing it all in C.

In addition, [PPM format specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) says that the red/green/blue values are interleaved, so the "colour plane" must be the last index:

```
... image[y + j][x + i][0] ...
```

unless there was some reordering of the input file while loading it into memory. You didn't show code that reads from the file, so it's hard to know whether it did any reordering.

---

Addition: reading and writing the file should follow raster ordering, that is, finish pixels of one line before proceeding to next line:

```
for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
    for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
        ...
    }
}
```

It is also recommended to do processing in this manner; this is not an absolute must, but it will reduce confusion, and might make your processing faster in addition (by using CPU cache more effectively).

Comment: No I didn't do any reordering within the .ppm reader/writer functions and so I went ahead and adjusted my indexing to the [y][x][color] format you specified and it gave much better results! Instead of filling in the box completely white, I'm actually detecting the edges correctly! This is great, but the image is still being overlapped three times as in the picture above. I was going to post all three functions but I thought it might be too much code to post for one question. Should I post all of it?

Comment: You might be able to figure it out by yourself. Please try, and describe your attempt if you fail; post the reading and writing functions if you want help about them.

Comment: Yup, I'm gonna try and see what I can find, I've been spending hours on the Sobel function and not finding anything. Now that you've enlightened me about the indexing being an issue, I'm gonna go down that route, it feels a lot more promising. Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to drop back in and say THANKS! Your suggestion worked and I was able to find out the error in my indexing soon after I posted the above comment and looked again at your post. That's the last time I ever say I am 100% sure that the problem is not this or that. (Honestly as a computer "scientist" I should have already have known better! I stand ashamed haha)